# Very large GeoTIFF dataset to GeoPackage

Tags: raster, gdal, mosaic, geopackage

I'm trying to mosaic a large GeoTIFF dataset into a GeoPackage with Gdalwarp 
(no reprojection). There are 512 .tif files, each with a single 8-bit grayscale 
band, and 1 meter resolution. I'm using -cutline to clip the dataset to a 
slightly smaller extent.

I'm using the command

```
gdalwarp --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 35% -multi -of GPKG -wo SKIP_NOSOURCE=YES -co QUALITY=70 -cutline worldbounds.shp -csql "SELECT * FROM worldbounds WHERE country='TheCountry'" *.tif output.gpkg
```

GdalWarp initially outputs the dimensions as 1 824 323P x 1 662 148L

I expect this operation to take quite some time, but it's now been 7 days and there has been no other output than the message about the dimensions. 
GdalWarp.exe has been using 2-3% CPU and 5 GB of memory the entire time. The output.gpkg is still only 80 KB and has not been modified since I started the process. Since GdalWarp usually outputs each filename as it's being processed, I'm 
suspecting that something has gone wrong.

From experience with similar jobs, it seems that when the output image is larger than a certain size, the process will not move forward. Does anyone have experience with creating very large mosaic GeoPackages in GDAL (performance hints etc.)? I'd be very interested to hear if you've managed this with other software as well.

Comment: Does the command run fast if you use virtual raster as output format `-of VRT`?

Comment: I just tried this, and the command ran quite fast. The output was a 280 MB .vrt file. Do you have a suggestion for the next step?

Comment: My mistake, the vrt I created just referenced the first of my GeoTIFF files and contained an insane amount of metadata. I created a new, proper .vrt file with gdalbuildvrt.exe. I'm currently trying to feed the .vrt file to gdalwarp with GPKG as output. Was this the method you were thinking of?

Comment: My suggestion would have been to feed the VRT that was created by gdalwarp as an input for gdal_translate. But 280 MB .vrt file is huge for only 512 tiff files. I can't understand what happens.

Comment: The VRT got so huge because it contained the geometry of the cutline, which is a very detailed polygon outlining a large country's borders. But using gdal_translate instead of gdalwarp seems to give at least a tiny bit more feedback that things are moving forward. I can now see that the GeoPackage file being processed is slowly growing. A small improvement at least!

Comment: The detailed polygon is probably what is slowing it down? Try selecting out just the 1 country and saving it as its own shapefile, then you can skip the `-csql` Beyond that you could first rasterize the shape to the same SRS dimensions and then use it as a mask with `gdal_calc` In general divide and conquer approach may be the best bet vs. trying to do it all in one command. I'm guessing there are 512 tif files in the first place because combining them into one wouldn't be feasible?